# onCreateOptionsMenu is not called. Toolbar is showing but empty without any menus and icons

Tags: android, android-toolbar, androidx

I am trying to use toolbar in my simple app. It is showing but not displaying any options / icons that I have placed in my menu file. My minimum sdk is 16 and I have recently migrated my project to androidX. onCreateOptionMenu is not getting called either. if(getSupportActionbar()!=null) block is not getting called as I have configured noActionBar in style.xml. I don't know what am I missing.

```
       @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar Toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(Toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");
    }
   }
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
    Log.i("onCreate", "menu");
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
   }
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
<style name="HeaderBar">
    <item name="android:background">#F3F5FF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: what theme are you using ? could you please post your style.xml

Comment: i am using NoActionBar. please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is within a `Fragment` you would need to call  `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` within the `onCreate` method. It is further documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

Comment: This code is in activity. if i am using androidx, do i have to include support library like v7.appcompat?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is you are using a `NoActionBar` style  `enter code here`, that why `onCreateOptionMenu` is never called . change your parent base  theme to this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
 </style>
```